# pandas rolling get most frequent value in window

Tags: python, pandas

I was wondering how one could obtain the most frequent value of in a rolling window of a time series, i.e. something like

```
df.rolling(window = 2).rolling.count_values().idxmax()
```

Since for the column of a data frame, one can use

```
df["value"].count_values().idxmax()
```

However, I only get an error message reading  `'Rolling' object has no attribute 'count_values'`

Comment: actually that method is `value_counts()` not `count_values()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rolling().apply` with [mode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html#pandas.Series.mode) method:

```py
df.rolling(window = 3).apply(lambda x: x.mode()[0])
```

`x` will be a `pd.Series` object of length equal to window. `mode` method will return a list of most frequent values. `lambda` will return the first item from the list of modes.